# How to turn off Eclipse/GWT's native method formatting?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, format

I have a few native gwt methods in my java class that I would like to not use tab spacing for.

```
public static native int getScreenWidth() /*-{
    return $wnd.screen.width;
}-*/;
```

The middle line is automatically tabbed whenever I have Eclipse format the code.  I can't find a setting to get rid of this tab.  Is there a way to do this, or can I somehow have Eclipse not open these files with the GWT Java Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the GWT Java Editor uses the formatting preferences for JavaScript when formatting JSNI blocks.

Comment: How did you turn it off eventually? I only manage to turn it off through the Eclipse tags "@formatter:off/ @formatter:on". I turned off the Js and Java comments formatting, but no luck, it keeps on aligning the native code all the way to the right :(

Comment: When using the "GWT Java Editor" (not the Java Editor), JSNI is seen as "embedded JS", and code inside it is formatted as JS (not as "Java comment" or "JS comment"). If you want no re-format at all, I think you could use the "Java Editor" and disable formatting of "Java comments" (if that's possible)